# ComponentRef.destroy() does not apply custom animation as the component is destroyed

Tags: angular, typescript

I am calling `destroy()` on a `ComponentRef` instance from a component I created dynamically, and my custom Angular animations are not being applied.

They are applied when a regular component is destroyed, so why don't they get applied when you create/destroy a component manually? Is there another API for this?

Referring to this class:

```
/**
 * Represents an instance of a Component created via a {@link ComponentFactory}.
 *
 * `ComponentRef` provides access to the Component Instance as well other objects related to this
 * Component Instance and allows you to destroy the Component Instance via the {@link #destroy}
 * method.
 * @stable
 */
export declare abstract class ComponentRef<C> {
    // Other properties...

    /**
     * Destroys the component instance and all of the data structures associated with it.
     */
    abstract destroy(): void;
}
```

Comment: would you create an online example?